# How to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV for only 30% of data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

How to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV for only 30% of data in order to speed up the process.
My X.shape is 94456,100 and I'm trying to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearchCV but it's taking a verly long time. I'm runnig my code for several hours but still with no results.
My code looks like this:

```
# Random Forest

param_grid = [
{'n_estimators': np.arange(2, 25), 'max_features': [2,5,10,25], 
 'max_depth': np.arange(10, 50), 'bootstrap': [True, False]}
]

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

grid_search_forest = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
grid_search_forest.fit(X, y)

rf_best_model = grid_search_forest.best_estimator_


# Decsision Tree

param_grid = {'max_depth': np.arange(1, 50), 'min_samples_split': [20, 30, 40]}

grid_search_dec_tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
grid_search_dec_tree.fit(X, y)

dt_best_model = grid_search_dec_tree.best_estimator_


# K Nearest Neighbor

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
k_range = list(range(1, 31))
param_grid = dict(n_neighbors=k_range)
grid_search_knn = GridSearchCV(knn, param_grid, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

grid_search_knn.fit(X, y)

knn_best_model = grid_search_knn.best_estimator_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always sample a part of your data to fit your models. Although not designed for this purpose, `train_test_split` can be useful here (it can take care of shuffling, stratification etc, which in a manual sampling you would have to take care of by yourself):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.70)
```

By asking for `test_size=0.70`, your training data `X_train` will now be 30% of your initial set `X`.

You should now replace all the `.fit(X, y)` statements in your code with `.fit(X_train, y_train)`.

On a more general level, all these `np.arange()` statements in your grid look like overkill - I would suggest selecting some representative values in a list instead of going through a grid search in *that* detail. Random Forests in particular are notoriously insensitive in the number of trees `n_estimators`, and adding one tree at a time is hardly useful - go for something like `'n_estimators': [50, 100]`...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have one question. If I change my code to 'n_estimators': [50, 100] it will take only values 50 and 100. I would like to check which is the best from 2 to 25.

Comment: @DinkoJantoš your call. As I have tried to imply in the answer, in RF, and for non-small datasets, you cannot expect any significant change between `n_estimators=n` and `n_estimators=n+1`; you could always do, say, `[5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`.

Answer (score 0):

[ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html) fits very well to this problem. You can define your `cv` as:

```
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=.3)
```

This means setting aside and using 30% of your training data for validating each hyper-parameter setting. `cv=5` on the other hand will carry out a 5-fold cross validation, which means going through 5 `fit` and `predict` for each hyper-parameter setting.

So, this also requires very minimal change to your code. Just replace those `cv=5` or `cv=10` inside `GridSearchCV` with `cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=.3)` and you're done.

Comment: This will in fact prevent the code from performing CV at all, which is not what OP is asking.